# Key to boto3.client.get_batch_prediction() OutputURI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-machine-learning

I'm trying to download the Output file from boto3.client.get_batch_prediction().  I figure the key is the filename bit of OutputURI so I'm doing client:

```
    response = batch.get_batch_prediction()
    if response['Status'] == 'COMPLETED':
        key = response['OutputUri'][response['OutputUri'].find('Output_'):response['OutputUri'].find('.csv')+4]
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        s3.meta.client.download_file(settings.AWS_S3_BUCKET_OUTPUT, key, '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

But this returns

> An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not
>   Found

I take this to mean the file isn't there.  That means I've got my key wrong so how do I find it?

Comment: This might also be a permissions problem. Do you have the required permissions to call HeadObject on the key?

Comment: @spg that's what I thought and I've asked the administrator who tells me I have the permissions

Comment: S3 had a outage yesterday. Can you try again today?

Comment: I got the `key` wrong.  When I read the documentation carefully I clearly had put in the wrong `key`.  Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the key wrong.  Note to self: Read the Docs carefully.